# Trying to check if a checkbox is checked and applying a class

Tags: jquery

Hey I'm trying to check if a checkbox is checked and if it is, add a class to some other checkboxes so they are no longer able to be selected

```
$('.off').change(function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')) 
        $('input[name="hotl"]').addClass('blocked'); 
      else 
        $('input[name="hotl"]').removeClass('blocked')
    }
```

Comment: And was does not work? Are you aware of the missing `.` before `addClass`?

Comment: You may be interested in the [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method, which would DRY up that code a bit.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question is lacking a [mre], which should be relatively simple to create using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar).